# How to keep leading 0's and decimal format when converting XLSM to CSV

Tags: excel, vba

I reviewed several other questions discussing XLSM to CSV conversion while maintaining decimal format. The answers that I found were not using VBA and were more so saving the file manually. Code attached is meant to perform Copy range of values and paste as values and number format. These values are then formatted to 0.00. Whenever I convert my XLSM to CSV it will format the value to 0 instead of 0.00 . Other questions suggested saving the file as a text file and the correct wanted number format of 0.00 would appear. They did not when I tried. I have tried several times but have been unsuccessful such as pasting them as Values and Number format from another question that suggested it. How can I achieve this?

```
Sub FormatDecimal()

Sheet1.Range("C2:K100").NumberFormat = "0.00"

End Sub
```

```
Sub Main()

    'User given warning message
    Dim reply
    reply = MsgBox("Do you want to proceed?", vbYesNo)
    If reply = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    CopyValues
    WorksheetChange
    DeleteRowIfCostCode
    FormatDecimal
    PrepareExport
    CSV_Convert
        
End Sub
```

```
Sub CSV_Convert()
Dim FilePath        As String
FilePath = ThisWorkbook.FullName

Dim Ext             As String           ' file extension
Dim Fn              As String           ' file name
Dim Path            As String           ' file path
Dim Ffn             As String           ' full file name
Dim Sp()            As String
Dim CSVfile
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Foundation Budget Template")


' extracts number from 5th element and applies to file name
Sp = Split(FilePath, "\")
Fn = Sp(UBound(Sp))
Sp(7) = Split(Sp(4), "-")(0) & "import-TMP-IFI-REV12"
Ffn = Join(Sp, "\")
CSVfile = Ffn & ".CSV"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ws.Select
ws.Copy
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=CSVfile, FileFormat:=xlCSV, local:=True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ActiveWorkbook.Close True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True



End Sub
```

```
Sub CopyValues()

Sheets("Foundation Budget Template").Range("A1:K100").Copy
Sheets("Foundation Budget Template").Range("A1:K100").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

End Sub
```

Comment: Please read Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:
**https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve**

Comment: You need to be clear on the difference between *values* and *formats*.  The value can be 0, but the formatted value may *appear* as 0.00   Those are two different things, and CSV can either store values (as the number 0 for example) or formatted values *as text* (so enclosed in quotes), but not both.  What happens when you open that CSV will depend on what you use to open it, so maybe you can expand on what you need to *do* with the CSV's you're creating.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks as always Tim.

Comment: Its a problem I've had and just avoided by not using csv with excel whenever possible. I don't think csv/Excel is viable with leading zeroes. Even if you create a csv with leading 0's, when you re-open it in excel, the application automatically removes leading zeroes.